Can android studio plugin support embedded webview development?
We development the plugin using embedded webview，it can use on IDEA, but can not use in Android studio ,How to adapt ，not using swing。
We development the plugin using embedded webview，and can run on Andorid sandbox environment，but build zip is fail display page

You can try asking this question here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development. Make sure to provide an actual example with failing code and screenshots.
